# Firebaseui on iOS: can't set background color on customized subclassed login screen

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm subclassing the login screen of Firebaseui with:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseUI

class LoginViewControllerCustom: FUIAuthPickerViewController {
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.view.backgroundColor = .red

        let arr = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("LoginText", owner: nil)!
        let v = arr[0] as! UIView
        self.view.addSubview(v)
        
    }

}
```

My implementation works as I see the xib LoginText loaded on login screen.
But the background color is royally ignored.

How to enforce a bg color on the login screen from that subclass?

Edit: if I apply the answer below with  view.insertSubview(imageViewBackground, at: 0)

Here is what I get:

[image]

As you can see the image gets inserted under the view that holds the login button. If I set "at: 1" it completely cover the buttons and they can't be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem in an unexpected way.
On the delegate method that would load this controller, I changed:

```
 func authPickerViewController(forAuthUI authUI: FUIAuth) -> FUIAuthPickerViewController {
    return LoginViewControllerCustom(authUI: authUI)
 }
```

to

```
 func authPickerViewController(forAuthUI authUI: FUIAuth) -> FUIAuthPickerViewController {
        return LoginViewControllerCustom(nibName: nil, bundle: Bundle.main, authUI: authUI)
    }
```

The addition of Bundle.main solved the issue, and replaced the original controller by mine, which was several levels deeper until that.
Not sure exactly why, but this did solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to put "fake" image background:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    let imageViewBackground = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 
    width, height: height))
    imageViewBackground.backgroundColor = .red
    view.insertSubview(imageViewBackground, at: 0)
    let arr = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("LoginText", owner: nil)!
    let v = arr[0] as! UIView
    self.view.addSubview(v)
}
```

**Edit: try this it's not elegant but it solves the problem.**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let scrollView = view.subviews[0]
    scrollView.backgroundColor = .clear
    let contentView = scrollView.subviews[0]
    contentView.backgroundColor = .red
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -1, width: width, height: height))
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    backgroundImage.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
    view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)
}
```

Comment: thanks, please see my edited answer above.